# Select substring between two words in a long string

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a large string column called "HL7_MESSAGE" that I need to pull a string from several key words, as you'll see in the code below. I'm an Oracle person so the code was written and works in Oracle SQL but I need to convert it into SQL server code. SQL server doesn't have Regexp_substr function but I haven't been able to get this to work using charindex or Patindex. Basically I select a string between two strings and in the decode statements I look for if there is data missing between the two words/sections. If it just finds '.br\' then it's missing data and I just flag missing or filled. Anyway, code is below...if someone can decode it to SQL server version 2011 I would appreciate it.

CODE:

```
select

primary_key,

trim(REPLACE(trim(regexp_substr(hl7_message, 'RHRN:(.*)BIRTHDATE:', 1, 1, null, 1)),'\.br\',' ')) AS PATIENT_RHRN,

trim(REPLACE(trim(regexp_substr(hl7_message, 'PATIENT NAME:(.*)RHRN:', 1, 1, null, 1)),'\.br\',' ')) AS PATIENT_NAME,

trim(REPLACE(trim(regexp_substr(hl7_message, 'ULI:(.*)GENDER:', 1, 1, null, 1)),'\.br\',' ')) AS PATIENT_ULI,

decode(replace(to_char(regexp_substr(hl7_message,'FINDINGS:(.*)ADVERSE EVENTS:',1,1,'',1)),'\.br\'),NULL, 'missing', 'filled') FINDINGS_TO_ADVS_EVENTS_FLAG,

decode(replace(to_char(regexp_substr(hl7_message,'IMPRESSIONS:(.*)RECOMMENDATIONS:',1,1,'',1)),'\.br\'),NULL, 'missing', 'filled') IMPRESSION_TO_RECOMM_FLAG,

decode(replace(to_char(regexp_substr(hl7_message,'RECOMMENDATIONS:(.*)_____________________________',1,1,'',1)),'\.br\'),NULL, 'missing', 'filled') RECOMM_TO_SIG_UNDERLINE

   from TEST;
```

Thanks

Comment: The narrative helps, but sample data and desired results would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have provided below a quick example using patindex and substring to extract information from a string between two other strings, Hopefully this will act as a basis for you to be able to do the conversion.

```
DECLARE @a varchar(300) = 'this is a long string I will extract data from'

PRINT SUBSTRING(@a, PATINDEX('% long %', @a) + LEN('% long %')-2, PATINDEX('% extract %', @a) - (PATINDEX('% long %', @a) + LEN('% long %')-2))
```

The key is in using the two patindex patterns to determine the start point and length:

First find the end of the first string pattern (Patindex to find the start, len - 2 for the end):

```
Patindex(pattern, string) + LEN(pattern, string) - 2
```

Then to find the length, use Patindex to find the start of the second string, and subtract the start point found above.

```
Patindex(pattern, string) - (Patindex(start pattern, string) + LEN(start pattern, string) - 2 )
```

I hope that this helps.